# SQL update copied table from original table

Tags: sql-server

I'm having 2 tables A and B, they are on 2 different databases, B is a copy of A but A is updated frequently (data can be changed, deleted, or newly inserted) so every time I want to update B I have to drop B then use Import Data... to make a copy of A into B.

After that, I made a little program that will automatically truncate the table B then copy all data from A to insert into B. However, the data appear to be too big so it took quite an amount of time to fully update table B every time it runs.

I wonder if there's any other way to shorten the time to complete the task or any SQL query to update table B from A?

The server belongs to the company so I don't have permission to access SQL Server Agent. and the database version doesn't support creating an SSIS pakage as well

Comment: Why not just copy new data across?

Comment: Why do you copy it? Cannot you just use the original?

Comment: I have to work and test on the original data so I made a copy of it. And in order to make the test run correct, I have to get the latest data without ruining the original one

Comment: So just copy the new data...

Comment: The program using this data is running at 1 am and 1 pm so it has to be updated at 1 am and 1 pm and do it manually if possible though I want to see if we can do it any easier and don't have to wake up at 1 am every morning

Comment: Schedule your program to run, and just copy new data, using an insert query which pulls from the other database, and a where clause which excludes any existing data.

Comment: If the original table have rows deleted the copied table may not have those rows delete

Comment: @hvtanh07, the `source` table has a primary key? And, does it have 'update_at'/'inserted_at' columns or can you ask the maintainers to add and keep such columns updated? And, lastly, how your "little program" communicates with the `source` and in which language is it written?

Comment: The source table doesn't have such columns and I don't think I have permission nor the maintainer will add it to the table. And for the program, I used Dataset to get all the data from the table and fill in a DataTable then use query to insert those data into the copied table with sqlConnection.